# Position div to left without float css

Tags: html, css

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BdRts/)** and the code below is what i did...can anyone help me...i want to do something like the second one but without using **FLOAT**

**HTMl**

```
   <div class="img-container">
        <div class="img"></div>Cristiano Ronaldo</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>I want this but without using float can ayone help??
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="img-container">
        <div class="img" style="float:left;"></div>Cristiano Ronaldo</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.img {
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:brown;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the css you need;

```
div.img {
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:brown;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:5px;
        vertical-align:top;
}
```

If you remove the float inline style and add vertical-align: top; it works :)

Comment: Your welcome. Please mark the post answered for future viewers :)